# customized digital clock in android

Tags: android

hi i want to display time in my application in the format of HH:mm AM/PM. Digital clock includes seconds also. That is HH:mm:ss am/pm. how to avoid showing seconds. Is there any possible way. Kindly help me out.

Comment: i am using digital clock to display my time

Comment: Try this : http://bakhtiyor.com/page/6/

Answer (score 5):

You have to make a clone of the file `DigitalClock.java` to use in your application, modify in the following manner:-

```
private final static String m12 = "h:mm aa";
private final static String m24 = "k:mm";
```

The path of DigitalClock.java :
[`Here`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/DigitalClock.java)

Comment: As all the properties of the DigitalClock are private, you'll have to copy and paste the source as described.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

// ... 
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
String formatted = format.format(myDate);
```