# Android: DigitalClock remove seconds

Tags: java, android, clock, digital

I used this code for adding a clock to my app:

```
  <DigitalClock 
android:id="@+id/digitalclock"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:textSize = "30sp"
/>
```

The problem is that it shows also seconds..there is a simple and fast way for hide those? I need just hours and minutes in hh:mm format instead of hh:mm:ss! any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579614/customized-digital-clock-in-android), for anyone else looking for a working answer, here it is:

1. Clone/copy `DigitalClock.java` from android source
2. Change format strings within new `CustomDigitalClock`

   ```
   package com.example;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.res.Resources;
   import android.database.ContentObserver;
   import android.os.Handler;
   import android.os.SystemClock;
   import android.provider.Settings;
   import android.text.format.DateFormat;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import java.util.Calendar;

   /**
    * You have to make a clone of the file DigitalClock.java to use in your application, modify in the following manner:-
    *      private final static String m12 = "h:mm aa";
    *      private final static String m24 = "k:mm";
    */

   public class CustomDigitalClock extends TextView {

       Calendar mCalendar;
       private final static String m12 = "h:mm aa";
       private final static String m24 = "k:mm";
       private FormatChangeObserver mFormatChangeObserver;

       private Runnable mTicker;
       private Handler mHandler;

       private boolean mTickerStopped = false;

       String mFormat;

       public CustomDigitalClock(Context context) {
           super(context);
           initClock(context);
       }

       public CustomDigitalClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
           initClock(context);
       }

       private void initClock(Context context) {
           Resources r = context.getResources();

           if (mCalendar == null) {
               mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
           }

           mFormatChangeObserver = new FormatChangeObserver();
           getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                   Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mFormatChangeObserver);

           setFormat();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
           mTickerStopped = false;
           super.onAttachedToWindow();
           mHandler = new Handler();

           /**
            * requests a tick on the next hard-second boundary
            */
           mTicker = new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       if (mTickerStopped) return;
                       mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                       setText(DateFormat.format(mFormat, mCalendar));
                       invalidate();
                       long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                       long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
                       mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
                   }
               };
           mTicker.run();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
           super.onDetachedFromWindow();
           mTickerStopped = true;
       }

       /**
        * Pulls 12/24 mode from system settings
        */
       private boolean get24HourMode() {
           return android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getContext());
       }

       private void setFormat() {
           if (get24HourMode()) {
               mFormat = m24;
           } else {
               mFormat = m12;
           }
       }

       private class FormatChangeObserver extends ContentObserver {
           public FormatChangeObserver() {
               super(new Handler());
           }

           @Override
           public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
               setFormat();
           }
       }

   }
   ```
3. Reference custom class within in layout xml

   ```
   <com.example.CustomDigitalClock
       android:id="@+id/fragment_clock_digital"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="DigitalClock" />
   ```
4. Load CustomDigitalClock within activity/fragment

   ```
   CustomDigitalClock dc = (CustomDigitalClock)
   mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_clock_digital);
   ```

Comment: Works great! Only you can remove row: Resources r = context.getResources(); It is not used anywhere.

Comment: Calling registerContentObserver without unregistering will cause memory leaks. I found that everytime an activity with this clock in it was closed by the OS, the activity was retained in the heap.

Answer (score 2):

The [DigitalClock Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html) states:

> ### Class Overview
>
> Like AnalogClock, but digital. Shows seconds. FIXME: implement
> separate views for hours/minutes/seconds, so proportional fonts don't
> shake rendering

Judging by the `FIXME`, the ability to hide portions of DigitalClock might be implemented eventually. I didn't find anything currently in the Javadoc or source code that would do what you want it to.

Unless you want to write your own class that extends DigitalClock (or your own clock implementation altogether), you could just cover the seconds portion of the DigitalClock with another element if it would serve your purpose.