# how to make digital clock display only hours and minutes

Tags: android, clock, digital, hour, minute

I have a digital clock on an activity in my app and I want to display only hours and minutes on it and don't want to display seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: DigitalClock remove seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610549/android-digitalclock-remove-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

The system sends a broadcast event at the exact beginning of every minutes based on system clock. The most reliable way is to do it like this :

```
BroadcastReceiver _broadcastReceiver;
private final SimpleDateFormat _sdfWatchTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
private TextView _tvTime;

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    _broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0)
                    _tvTime.setText(_sdfWatchTime.format(new Date()));
            }
        };

    registerReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (_broadcastReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
}
```

Don't forget however to initialize your TextView beforehand (to current system time) since it is likely you will pop your UI in the middle of a minute and the TextView won't be updated until the next minute happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DigitalClock extends TextView {

    Calendar mCalendar;
    private final static String m24 = "k:mm";
    private FormatChangeObserver mFormatChangeObserver;

    private Runnable mTicker;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private boolean mTickerStopped = false;

    String mFormat;

    public DigitalClock(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initClock(context);
    }

    public DigitalClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initClock(context);
    }

    private void initClock(Context context) {
        if (mCalendar == null) {
            mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        }

        mFormatChangeObserver = new FormatChangeObserver();
        getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mFormatChangeObserver);

        setFormat();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        mTickerStopped = false;
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        mHandler = new Handler();

        /**
         * requests a tick on the next hard-second boundary
         */
        mTicker = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mTickerStopped) return;
                    mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    setText(DateFormat.format(mFormat, mCalendar));
                    invalidate();
                    long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
                    mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
                }
            };
        mTicker.run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        mTickerStopped = true;
    }


    private void setFormat() {
            mFormat = m24;

    }

    private class FormatChangeObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public FormatChangeObserver() {
            super(new Handler());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            setFormat();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this custom view. This works with gingerbread also. Change the time format to your liking.(m24)